# RTLabel issue (Number of Line) & NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail

Tags: objective-c

I am using RTLabel from https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel, I need to give Number of lines(at list 4 lines) and after set lineBreakMode as NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail.

How can i set this...?

Comment: Goto `RTLabel.m` File and `- (void)initialize` Method and you can set there your mode. `_lineBreakMode = RTTextLineBreakModeWordWrapping;`

Comment: @NiravKotecha I have tried using _lineBreakMode but my requirement is to show 4 lines and if the text is more than 4 lines, RTLabel should show 3 dots in the end.

Comment: i have also tried for 4 lines but can't find it. RTLabel Class is UIView type not UILabel. so we can't find it numberOfLines property in that class.